# Webpage styling not working after changes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I was making some changes on the header.php file of my wordpress site, related to the flag icons displayed on the top of the webpage.

After that, I loaded back the page and suddenly it all appeared messed. I undoed all the changes I've previosly done, saved and I don't know why but the page is still messed.

Just so you can see [how it should be](http://www.pousadafloresdocerrado.com.br/site) and [how it's actually looking like](http://www.pousadafloresdocerrado.com.br/).

I'm sort of desperate because of it, so any clue in what could be causing this is gonna be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion would be try adding those icons again to working design, and come back here if you stuck, as it's near to impossible for person to find out bug when one do not know where all changes are made before. I wish you luck!

Comment: Also as answer posted by@Florin Pop could be reason in some cases, but i have looked into yours, but there is no issue as he states else **"if you forgot to add some styles/other files".**

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes with wordpress it needs a bit of time until it's changing. Also try pressing F5 to force refresh, or clear your cache.
Also, you might forgot to add some styles or other file.